# How can I get a bootable version of ububtu

Tags: system-installation

I tried downloading "Ubuntu-16.04.1 desktop-amd64.iso. I used imgburn to load it on a disk. It would not boot with my Lenovo Ideacenter desktop (which is Intel based and has a UEFI interface for its boot process. Can I download a bootable Ubuntu image? If so please explain.

Comment: The disc image you downloaded should be bootable. Have you tried following the steps given [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI)?

Comment: The image I reated with infrarecorder was not bootable. If it required more detailed instructions, please help.

Comment: I tried again using a new download of imgburn with the selections for Joliet bootable image burning on a second (not the target) desktop computer. The resulting disk also did not boot on the target desktop computer, with the target system asking me to insert a Windows Restoration disk when I selected Ubuntu as the operating system as opposed to Windows 10 which boots to the Windows desktop. I don't know what to do next. gd5figgy@gmail.com